# Insert Word shape at cursor position

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Im looking for a way to insert an MS Word Shape at cursor position. At the moment I have the following code which inserts a shape at a predetermined location:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range CurrRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;

        //Get the id of the MS Word shape to be inserted
        int shapeId = (int)MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRoundedRectangle;
        //Get the value of the name attribute from the selected tree view item
        string nodeText = treeViewItem.GetAttribute("name");

        //Add a new shape to the MS Word designer and set shape properties
        var shape = CurrRange.Document.Shapes.AddShape(shapeId, 170, 200, 100, 20);
        shape.AlternativeText = String.Format("Alt {0}", nodeText);
        shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Text = nodeText;
        shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Font.Size = 8;
```

The location where the shape gets inserted is hardcoded:

This can be seen from the 2nd and 3rd parameters of the `AddShape()` method:

170 = position measured in points to the left edge of the autoshape

200 = position measured in points to the top edge of the autoshape

I've had a look at the properties and methods of my Range object but cannot seem to find any which store the position values which I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final parameter to AddShape is an Anchor, which expects a range object. Try passing your range into that:

```
var shape = CurrRange.Document.Shapes.AddShape(shapeId, 0, 0, 100, 20,CurrRange);
```

Update:  It looks like there is a [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/worddev/thread/6fff35c7-25e6-46ab-be99-23bf88557e3f) in Word 2010 documents that it doesn't respect the Anchor.  Save the document as a .doc file and test again, it does anchor it to the beginning of the paragraph if you do that.  The link above is just to the microsoft forums, I could not find the connect bug report for the issue.

A workaround would be to specify the top and left based on the location of the selection:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range CurrRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;

//Get the id of the MS Word shape to be inserted
int shapeId = (int)MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRoundedRectangle;

//Get the value of the name attribute from the selected tree view item
string nodeText = "Hello World";

var left = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.get_Information(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage);
var top = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.get_Information(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage);

//Add a new shape to the MS Word designer and set shape properties
var shape = CurrRange.Document.Shapes.AddShape(shapeId, left, top, 100, 20);
shape.AlternativeText = String.Format("Alt {0}", nodeText);
shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Text = nodeText;
shape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Font.Size = 8;
```

Comment: I've tried this already, it doesn't work.The shape is still inserted at the same location

Comment: I updated my answer with some information I found on Microsoft's forums.

Comment: I've also came across that post on msdn - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/53d9baff-c10c-4655-822a-4c7a1b0fa885/ However left and top values always need to be incremented by 70 otherwise the shape gets inserted a few cm above and to the left of the cursor...This is very strange and I'm not exactly sure why it must be done but it does seem to be working.Thanks for the effort, marking as answered

Comment: I used ```var top = sel.Information[wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage]``` to get the location of the cursor, then created the shape, but it was in the wrong location. I had to reset the top location of the shape after creating the shape with ```shape.Top = top;``` to get it in the right place.